# Coping a worksheet without it being activated

Tags: vba, excel

I'd like to copy a worksheet at the end of my workbook without it becoming active.

I use this code to copy my "Template" sheet at the end:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template").Copy after:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
```

But then my new sheet "Template(2)" become the active sheet. 
I'd like to remain on "Template" even after the copy.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible?

It's not. `.Copy` activates the new sheet, that's just how it is. However nothing stops you from (re-)activating the original sheet after:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template")
    .Copy after:=ThisWorkbook.Workheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
    .Activate
End With
```

Notice I'm using the `Worksheets` collection here. The `Sheets` collection can contain non-worksheet objects, such as a `Chart` sheet, which is typically not what you're looking for - the `Worksheest` collection only contains actual `Worksheet` object.

Note that finding your template sheet in the `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets` collection everytime you need to use it is not a necessity, and makes your code more frail than it needs to be.

Each Excel object (VBA object actually) has a `(Name)` property (on top of the `Name` property which refers to whatever the worksheet is labelled as) that you can edit in the *Properties* pane (press <kbd>F4</kbd> in the editor) - that name must be a legal VBA identifier, and what VBA does with it is pretty nifty: it declares a global-scope object variable with that name, so if you name your "Template" sheet `TemplateSheet`, then you can do this:

```
With TemplateSheet
    .Copy after:=ThisWorkbook.Workheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
    .Activate
End With
```

And so on for every "static" worksheet (i.e. sheets that aren't generated by code). By referring to worksheets by their `Name` property (the tab label), your code will start failing as soon as a user decides to name the tab something else. By referring to the corresponding global-scope identifier, you can label the worksheet tab whatever you like, the code won't care at all.

Comment: Thanks for all those information, very interesting, in my case i'll use Activate then and use the property name.